# Need help to close a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have to do a loop inside a thread with this condition:

```
while(running)
```

( `running` is a sentinel boolean variable set to `true` )

But when I click on a button ( `Qt -> QPushButton` ), it calls a function ( `pause()` ) and `running` has to be set to `false`.

My thread's code looks like this:

```
DWORD CServeurTcp::ClientThread(SOCKET soc, BluetoothThread *_bt)
{
    ifstream fichier("test.txt", ios::in);
    string ligne, mess_crypt, donnees, cut;
    int compteurReception = 0;

    if(fichier)
    {
        while(running)
        {
            if((_bt->getReception() != 0)&&(compteurReception != _bt->getReception()))
            {
                compteurReception = _bt->getReception();

                getline(fichier, ligne);
                cut = ligne.substr (0,12);
                cryp->vigenere_crypter(cut,mess_crypt,"VIGE");
                donnees = salle + " - " + mess_crypt;
                emis = send(soc, donnees.c_str(), strlen(donnees.c_str()), 0);
                if(emis == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Affiche_Erreurs( WSAGetLastError() );
                else
                    cout << "Nombre de caracteres envoyes: " << strlen(donnees.c_str()) << endl;
            }
        Sleep(1000);
        }
        fichier.close();
    }
    else
    cout << endl << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier !" << endl;

    ExitThread(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class CServeurTcp;

struct thread_param_client{
   CServeurTcp* cli;
   SOCKET soc;
   BluetoothThread *_bt;
};

class CServeurTcp
{
private:
    SOCKET client;
    int erreur, emis, recus;
    bool running;
    DWORD ClientThread(SOCKET, BluetoothThread*);
    string salle;

    Vigenere *cryp;
    BluetoothThread *_bth;

public:
    CServeurTcp(string, unsigned short, string, BluetoothThread*);
    ~CServeurTcp();
    int pause();

static DWORD WINAPI ThreadLauncher_client(void *p)
{
    struct thread_param_client *Obj = reinterpret_cast<struct thread_param_client*>(p);
    CServeurTcp *s = Obj->cli;
    return s->ClientThread(Obj->soc,Obj->_bt);
}
};
```

The `pause()` method has to set `running` to false and then stop the loop of the thread, but it didn't work...
How could I do to achieve this ?

( close the loop of the thread to close it when i call `pause()` )

Thanks

Comment: Do you know mutexes etc.?

Comment: Well, then you know know what to learn next :) That's one of the problems with threads.

Comment: Well, i just finish a video which explain the mutex with an example, but i don't really understand why should I use them in my program.

The running' loop content is not to lock, but is set to run while i say stop when pushing a button ( and call **pause()**)

Comment: @RichardDecoux: You should complete the following problems first: https://deadlockempire.github.io/

Comment: Instead of watching random YouTube videos, read a good book on how to write multi-threaded programs. It will fully explain what you need here and why.

Answer (score 4):

`running` is not atomic nor protected with a mutex, so accessing it from multiple threads is not safe and your program has a data race - thus its behaviour is undefined and you can assume nothing about its result.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand what you mean :s
My program is a server and the *running* attribut allow me to stop cleanly the server when i stop it.
In fact, it waits the end of the loop to exit.

Comment: Then read up on the C++ memory model as well as std::atomic and std::mutex.